# Remove (or customize) 'Search' from help menu

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsmenu

My app has the default 'Help' menu. I have removed the 'Help' entry and added a Support entry that links to a forum on my website.

The help menu nib looks like this:

[image: Menu in nib]

But once I have the app up and running a new menu item has been suck in:

[image: Menu with search]

How can I make the search go away? (Or even better, how could I make it launch a url with params such as http://mywebsite.com/support?search=XXXXX).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're looking for **NSUserInterfaceItemSearching** protocol.
Return a single search result item and use it to open your custom URL.

```
- (void)searchForItemsWithSearchString:(NSString *)searchString resultLimit:(NSInteger)resultLimit matchedItemHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *items))handleMatchedItems
{
    handleMatchedItems(@[searchString]);
}

- (NSArray *)localizedTitlesForItem:(id)item
{
    return @[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Search for '%@' on my website", [item description]]];
}

- (void)performActionForItem:(id)item
{
    // Open your custom url assuming item is actually searchString
}
```

Comment: For those coming to Mac development via Mac Catalyst: this is not supported in Mac Catalyst apps.

Answer (score 5):

I have found the way to remove the search bar (but not to customize it).

Just assign a menu that is not used to the help menu:

```
NSMenu *unusedMenu;
unusedMenu = [[NSMenu alloc] initWithTitle:@"Unused"];

NSApplication *theApp;
theApp = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
theApp.helpMenu = unusedMenu;
```

The documentation mentions this in the helpMenu property of the NSApplication class.

Answer (score 3):

You probably don't want to get rid of that search bar, since you can still use it to search for menu items!

[image: Searching for Menu Items]

As I'm sure you know, this search box will only show Help Topics if your app comes with an Apple Help Book, which can be made by following [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/ProvidingUserAssitAppleHelp/authoring_help/authoring_help_book.html).

I'm afraid I don't know of a way to override the search bar's behaviour, but if you don't want to write documentation for your app, I think it would be better to keep the search bar, even if you can't search your forum for help.

Comment: It's only briefly mentioned in NSApplication as a spotlight help or something.

Comment: The current phrase in the docs is *Spotlight for Help*.

Answer (score 2):

I remove the Search bar from the Help menu in mac development by entering a single space after Help like "Help ". It looks funny but works properly.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: My app is written in Java. So, this trick is the only solution I can apply. And it works.

Answer (score 2):

@zhoudu's answer worked for me.  I translated it into Swift 5.0:

```
let unusedMenu = NSMenu(title: "Unused")
NSApplication.shared.helpMenu = unusedMenu
```

Put it into your `AppDelegate`.

Answer (score 2):

The answers from @pointum and @zhoudu aren't supported on Mac Catalyst apps, so here's an option for that.

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6673807/462162), the search field is added by macOS. I looked for a [plist key](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/GeneralPurposeKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009253-SW1) to disable it, but didn't find anything. Then I started messing with the `buildMenuWithBuilder` method. I had to change my `AppDelegate` class to be a subclass of `UIResponder` instead of `NSObject` and then I could override that method in my `AppDelegate`. Once that was running, it took a few tries to do something useful with it.

**Attempt 1:** I tried removing the first element of the Help menu, which was the search field.

```
- (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder {
    [super buildMenuWithBuilder:builder];
    [builder replaceChildrenOfMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuHelp fromChildrenBlock:^(NSArray<UIMenuElement *> *currentChildren) {
        NSMutableArray *newChildren = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:currentChildren];
        [newChildren removeObjectAtIndex:0 withSafeChecks:TRUE];
        return newChildren;
    }];
}
```

But the search field is added after this method runs, so this code only removed the "[app name] Help" element that I wanted to keep.

**Attempt 2:** I tried taking the "[app name] Help" menu element from the default menu, then adding it to a new menu and replacing the default help menu with that:

```
- (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder {
    [super buildMenuWithBuilder:builder];
    UIMenuElement *helpItem = [[builder menuForIdentifier:UIMenuHelp].children objectAtIndex:0];
    UIMenu *helpMenu = [UIMenu menuWithTitle:@"Help " children:[NSArray arrayWithObject:helpItem]];
    [builder replaceMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuHelp withMenu:helpMenu];
}
```

But macOS is not so easily tricked; it still identified this as a help menu and added the search field. Even when I changed the menu name to "Help " as shown here, I got the same result.

**Attempt 3:** Finally I had to make a new help action, add it to a new help menu, AND name the help menu with an extra space. Only when I did all three things did macOS stop adding the search field:

```
- (void)buildMenuWithBuilder:(id<UIMenuBuilder>)builder {
    [super buildMenuWithBuilder:builder];
    UIAction *helpAction = [UIAction actionWithTitle:@"[app name] Help" image:nil identifier:@"simpleHelp" handler:^(__kindof UIAction *action) {
        // my help code
    }];
    UIMenu *helpMenu = [UIMenu menuWithTitle:@"Help " children:[NSArray arrayWithObject:helpAction]];
    [builder replaceMenuForIdentifier:UIMenuHelp withMenu:helpMenu];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [@arlomedia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60610342/1107226)'s answer, and using Swift 5.x, Xcode 11.x, I created an extension to `appDelegate` that works in Mac Catalyst and does both things the OP wanted:

1. Create a custom Help menu without the *Search* item and with a *Support* item.
2. Point the custom *Support* menu item to a web page.

```swift
import UIKit

extension AppDelegate {
    
    /// selector function to open the desired web page
    @objc func openSupportPage() {
        if let url = URL(string: "https://mywebsite.com/support?search=XXXXX") {
            UIApplication.shared.open(url)
        }
    }
    
    /// buildMenu override to customize the default menu
    override func buildMenu(with builder: UIMenuBuilder) {
        
        // ensure we're working with the main menu; and, if so, run `super`!
        guard builder.system == .main else { return }
        super.buildMenu(with: builder)
        
        // remove the "stock" help menu
        builder.remove(menu: .help)
        
        // create the Support help item; gave it a shortcut key of "s" (Command-S)
        let supportHelpItem = UIKeyCommand(
            title: "Support",
            action: #selector(openSupportPage),
            input: "s",
            modifierFlags: [.command])
        
        // create a custom menu to appear as *Help* menu on menu bar
        let myHelpMenu = UIMenu(
            title: "Help ",                 // note the space after "Help"
            children: [supportHelpItem])    // add the *Support* item to the menu
        
        // insert the *Help* menu at the end of the existing menu bar items
        // (after the Window item) where the Help menu would've appeared
        builder.insertSibling(myHelpMenu, afterMenu: .window)
    }
}
```