# How to Remove the Search Option that Appears under Help in the Menu Bar

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, menu

Im new to OS X Development ..I can see that there is a search box that appears below the Help Menu item.

[image]

I cannot find a way to delete this as it does not show up in the StoryBoard.

Please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove (or customize) 'Search' from help menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075413/remove-or-customize-search-from-help-menu)

Answer (score 1):

There is a question about it, try this:

```
let unusedMenu = NSMenu(title: "Unused")
NSApplication.shared.helpMenu = unusedMenu
```

[Remove (or customize) 'Search' from help menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22075413/remove-or-customize-search-from-help-menu)